# What is the best way to convert character time variables from multiple files when timezone is unknown?

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, lubridate

Lets say I have 2 files, each with a date column, e.g. `2022-11-14` and a timestamp, e.g. `18:36` column. No prior information is given on timezone this information was taken from. In my code, I create a new column, `date_time_X` corresponding to the file # where I concatenate date and time `paste(as.character(date), timestamp)`.

I've discovered that base R's `POSIXct` default timezone is system-specific while lubridate's `ymd_hds` timezone defaults to UTC, so now I'm defaulting to applying `ymd_hds(paste(as.character(date), timestamp))` across both files to keep consistent timezones, since I will be subtracting `date_time_1` from `date_time_2` to get a time difference `diff_time = date_time_2 - date_time_1` .

My question is, what is the best approach to handle datetime variables from these different files when timezone is unknown? Should data be read in as UTC? Is there a way to completely remove the timezone component? I don't want to assume the data was collected at my local time, but I'm also not sure if defaulting to UTC is an acceptable approach. Ideally, removing the timezone would be the best option, but I'm not sure if this is possible without leaving the variables as character columns.

Comment: Removing the timezone seems about the same to me as assuming everything is UTC or any other particular timezone.

Comment: You are interested in difference between the two times. The difference is not location specific. as long as both times are coded in the same location/timezone, the difference will be the same.